# Android App with rest api php codeigniter admin panel

Tags: java, php, android, api

want to connect Android App with rest api php codeigniter admin panel I am facing problem to connect with admin panel codeigniter...rest api connect with login submit button

```
/* PHP */
<?php include ('header.php');?>
<div class="container"?>
    <?php echo form_open('logincontroller/admin_login', ['class'=>'form-horizontal']) ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>LOGIN</legend>
        <div class="row"><!-- user email field -->
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <?php echo form_input(['name'=>'email' , 'class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Email','value'=>set_value('email')]);?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <?php echo form_error('email');?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputPassword" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Password</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <?php echo form_password(['name'=>'password' , 'class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Password','value'=>set_value('password') ]);?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <?php echo form_error('password');?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
                <?php echo form_reset(['name'=>'reset','value'=>'Reset','class'=>'btn btn-default']);
                echo form_submit(['name'=>'submit','value'=>'Login' ,'class'=>'btn btn-primary']);?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
<?php include ('footer.php');?>
```

Comment: show any piece of code where you are trying to connect with api

Comment: want to attach rest api with login submit button

Comment: I think @MustanserIqbal is saying that you should show what you tried

Comment: this is code is the part of web. show your android code. where you are trying to connect with api

Answer (score 0):

I think you will want to do something with the form action field or capture the submit event with javascript and do an ajax request to your android app.

Answer (score 0):

```
         HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String responseString = null;
            try {

                HttpResponse response = client.execute(new HttpGet("http://api.amid.tech/product/0"));
                StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                    out.close();
                    responseString = out.toString();
                    //Whatever you wanna do with the response
                } else {
                    //Close the connection.
                    response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                    Log.e("Anas", statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
                    throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
class LoginController extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library("session");
    }

    public function index()
    {
        if($this->session->userdata("id"))
        {
            return redirect('admincontroller/dashboard');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('index');
        }
    }

    public function admin_login()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'E-mail', 'required|trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters("<p class='text-danger'>", "</p>");

        if ($this->form_validation->run())
        {
            $email = $this->input->post('email');
            $password = $this->input->post('password');
            $link = 'http://api.amid.tech/admin/' . $email . '/' . $password;
            $data = (array)json_decode(@file_get_contents($link, true));
                        if (isset($data) && count($data) == 0)
                        {
                            $this->session->set_flashdata('login_failed','Invalid User Name Password');
                            $this->load->view('index');
                        }
                        else if ($email == $data['email'] && $password == $data['password'])
                        {
                            $Record = array(
                                "id" => $data["id"],
                                "name" => $data["name"],
                                "email" => $data["email"],
                                "password" => $data["password"]
                            );
                            $this->session->set_userdata($Record);
                            return redirect('admincontroller/dashboard');
                            //$this->load->view('admin/dashboard');
                        }
        }
        else
        {
            // echo"false";
            $this->load->view('index');
            //echo validation_errors('');
        }
    }
    public function logout()
    {
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect('logincontroller/index');


    }


}

?>
```

correct answer